# What series test would you use on these and why?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I just started learning series , I am trying to put everything together...I have few some few random problems just to see what kind of strategy you would use here...

1. $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^n}{(2^n)^2}$
2. $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac2{(2n - 1)(2n + 1)}$;  telescoping series ?
3. $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(1 + \ln^2 n)}$
4. $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{n (n + 1)}}$;   integral test ? cause you could do u-sub?

Comment: Go to the FAQ section and follow direction how to use LaTeX to write properly mathematics in this site.

Comment: In your first series, is it *really $\,(2^n)^2=2^{2n}\,$ ? Why then not to write it in the second form?

Comment: Kaish ...yes test for convergence....sorry i should have said it

Comment: DonAntonio it is written like that...

Comment: It’s not actually obvious from the main faq link above where to look for help writing mathematics here; [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is probably the best starting point, and [this one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto) is also helpful.

Comment: Wait, wait … does $\ln^2 n$ mean $(\ln n)^2$, or $\ln\ln n$? I had assumed the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first i would use the root test, as this yields a pretty simple result. The ratio test will work too, just the calculation will be longer. In fact nearly every test should work for this one.

For the second I would use comparism test as it looks pretty much like 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$
The root and the ratio test won't work here, as both would yield the result 1 which gives you nothing about convergence or divergence. Cauchy condensation could work but won't be so nice. Integral test will work too.

The third one is a bit more complicated. I would use comparism test or maybe cauchy condensation. (While the cauchy condensation some comparisn will be necessary).

For the fourth i would use comparism again as it looks pretty much like 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$$
Here ratio and root test won't work again, Cauchy condensation might work but will not be very trivial.

A small remark for series number 2, with partial fracition decomposition you get a telescoping series with limit 1
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2}{(2n-1) (2n+1)} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n+1}=1$$

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time and explaining this...i totally understand these problems better

Comment: @AgapeTwentyone glad i could help :)

Answer (score 3):

General **and mixed** hints:

$$\frac{2}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$$

$$\frac{n}{4}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty$$

$$\frac{2^n}{2^n(1+n^2\log^22)}\le\frac{1}{\log^22}\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Comment: thank you sir!...very unique

Comment: @AgapeTwentyone, good you made me come back here: there was a mistake in the first one. Check that.

Answer (score 2):

#1 is just teeming with $n$th powers. Use the root test. #2 and #4 can be compared with $\sum 1/n^p$ for some $p$ (limit comparison). For #3 I would compare with $$\sum\frac{1}{n\ln n}$$ (which diverges by a standard application of the integral test).

Comment: thank you very much for number 3.

Comment: @AgapeTwentyone But see my question above, in a comment to your question. If it means $(\ln n)^2$, the same principle applies, but with the opposite conclusion. We're right at the convergence/divergence boundary here.